# Angular 4 + Universal - Send status code 404 in header for /404 pagecomponent

Tags: javascript, angular, express, angular2-routing, angular-universal

On searching and going through several StackOverflow questions what I got is : Headers come from responses served by servers, so this is not a thing.

so decided to solve it from server.ts file but not able to find any clues.

Below is my server.ts file any help will really take me out of this stuck process.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
.then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src')

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: yes, but still stuck in this, can u tell me in more example how i can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Providers to the `renderModuleFactory` method (see [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-server/renderModuleFactory)).

This way you can inject the request and the response object to the Angular App. [This post](https://medium.com/@albanx/angular-server-side-rendering-5788d7b3c59c) e.g. explains this method quite well.

Then, in your 404-component, you can get the response object and set the 404 status if you are on server side.

Comment: thankyou so much for your help, can u provide me an example to use it

Comment: Hi am also same 404 status code stuck in angular 9 and above, can u please help me out,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/70926063/8203291